# Is the posterior maximum always the same as the marginal's?

Tags: marginal-distribution, map-estimation

When I see plots of the conditional probabilities, marginals and joint distributions together they are mostly plot using Gaussians. It is not clear to me if this applies to every other distribution. For example, in this image [image]

the conditional f(x1|b) will always peak at the argmax of f(x1) because the joint distribution is a Gaussian and "slicing" it gives another identical Gaussian (up to scale) to the marginal. But is this always the case? I.e, when f(x1) != f(x1|b) do they still share the same maximum? Or, in other words. Is maximizing the posterior the same as maximizing the marginal in terms of result regardless they have different shapes?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the shapes of the distributions. By definition, $f(x) = f(x|b)$ means that $x$ is [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) of $b$. However you are not asking about equality of distributions, but only of their modes. It does need much math to give a counterexample, say that $x$ is life expectancy, so the mode of $f(x)$ is the most probable life expectancy in the whole population. Lets $b$ be some event, for example, a smoking packet of cigarettes a day, so $f(x|b)$ would be the most probable life expectancy for a person who smokes a packet of cigarettes a day--they are unlikely the same. The same can happen to any other conditional probability.

Comment: I am trying to understand this from a Variational Auto Encoders (VAEs) perspective. In VAEs, we try to maximize the posterior of the data given a latent variable, i.e., p(x|z). I am not sure why this is called as well the likelihood. The input to the encoder is a realization of X, X=x and we try to find the x that maximizes p(x|z) which it is the same x from the input X=x

Comment: @ElPotac probability of data given the parameters is the likelihood, not the posterior. But the same applies: there is no reason for conditional and marginal probabilities, or functions of the distributions, to be the same unless we are talking about independent variables.